# Adding constraints to tableview cell with swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add constratints with swift.

As you can see in the screenshot i have to put the image to inside of blue bubble box.

[image]

I used following line for width:

```
bubbleImageView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: bubbleImageView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: photoView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 50))
```

As you can see it is working well. (I know center x is not looking correct but width constraint is working i didn't add the centerx and centery constraints for now)

I am trying similiar code for height with following line:

```
bubbleImageView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: bubbleImageView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: photoView, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

And result:

[image]

Why this is not worked? Image size is fixed to 150x150. How can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, is the compression resistance priority of the photoView higher than the content hugging priority of the bubbleImageView? It should be or else the bubble will compress the image. Secondly, it seems the x value of the photoView is incorrect. What are you using for those constraints?